# Powershell : Invoke-WebRequest: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument {URI}

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie and trying to install a toolbox found on a URL.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri \ 'https://{location of toolbox}'
```

I get the following error when I try to run :

> Invoke-WebRequest: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'https:/**

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri \ 'https://{location of toolbox}'
```

PowerShell considers backslash (`\`) as the value for `Uri`. You probably need to simply remove the backslash.